# Perché a volte si usa il passato prossimo per descrivere un'abitudine?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar, tenses

‎Ho trovato la seguente espressione su Context Reverso:

> Ogni estate ho lavorato là, fino ai miei 18 anni.

Perché si usa il passato prossimo e no l'imperfetto se si descrive un'abitudine?

Comment: Non mi fiderei ciecamente di Context Reverso: mette insieme traduzioni ben fatte, mal fatte, automatiche...

Comment: @Charo Non necessariamente: "Lei fino a qualche anno fa andava a Cervia in un albergo..." https://books.google.de/books?id=ygULjkV9l4gC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22fino+a+qualche+anno+fa+andava%22&source=bl&ots=ZEl9z4MBNL&sig=ACfU3U0ke_eJvago424UkwjaGD-WWOdlbA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRrfPShp3pAhWiy6YKHXCICZMQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fino%20a%20qualche%20anno%20fa%20andava%22&f=false

Comment: @Nico:  Ma, a quanto ne so, se nella frase che esprime un'abitudine nel passato appare un'espressione che delimita il periodo di tempo, di solito non si usa l'imperfetto.

Comment: @Charo Vorrà dire che lo scrittore che cito ha bisogno di lezioni di italiano...

Comment: Per la verità, non troverei niente di strano in “lavoravo là ogni estate, fino ai miei diciotto anni”. Però trovo necessario invertire la costruzione, almeno così a orecchio.

Comment: @Charo Vedi anche "fino a 18 anni ero molto attivo, ora non lo sono più".

Comment: Ho trovato anche" NON AVEVO MAI  MANGIATO LA RIBOLLITA. FINORA! " su https://www.italymadeeasy.com/ask010/

Comment: @egreg Osservazione interessante! "Fino a x anni facevo il barista, poi..." mi sembra molto più accettabile di "facevo il barista fino a x anni, poi..."

Comment: @user11731289 Penso che le differenze di opinioni riguardino il "fino". In sua assenza, mi pare valga la mia risposta sotto. Riguardo al "fino" bisognerebbe proporre un'analisi più differenziata, che non so se ti interessi.

Comment: Tra "ho lavorato là ogni estate" e "lavoravo là ogni estate" c'è una differenza. Nel primo caso, il lavoro poteva durare o no per tutta l'estate (magari si trattava di un lavoretto di 3 giorni, ogni estate) - nel secondo, è più marcato che il lavoro durasse tutta la stagione.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica grazie.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Sì, anche questo è un punto da tenere in considerazione (anche se per la prima interpretazione sarebbero necessari ulteriori elementi espressi del tipo "per qualche giorno".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrivo una risposta basata sulle spiegazioni e gli esempi che appaiono nel libro *Nuovo Contatto C1. Corso di lingua e civiltà italiana per stranieri* di R. Bozzone Costa, M. Piantoni, E. Scaramelli e C. Ghezzi.

Hai ragione sul fatto che l'imperfetto si usa

> per esprimere al passato fatti ripetuti con carattere di **abitudine** (spesso segnalato da avverbi).

Ecco due esempi che appaiono sul libro sopra menzionato:

> - *Ogni giorno andavamo al mare*.
> - *Uscivo sempre alla sera*.

La tua domanda:

> Perché a volte si usa il passato prossimo per descrivere un'abitudine?

Perché se nella frase che esprime queste abitudini appare un'espressione che delimita il periodo di tempo, allora di solito non si usa l'imperfetto, ma il passato prossimo oppure il passato remoto:

> Con espressioni temporali di durata riferita al passato si usano il passato prossimo o il passato remoto:
>
> - *Ha studiato in Inghilterra dal 1987 al 1992*.
> - *Studiò russo per cinque anni*.
> - *Ha succhiato il dito fino ai cinque anni*.

È quello che accade nella frase della domanda, che è infatti molto simile all'ultimo esempio.

Questo ha a che vedere con l'*aspetto imperfettivo* che ha appunto l'imperfetto. Secondo l'[articolo sull'imperfetto dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/imperfetto_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/)

> Dal punto di vista dell'aspetto è una forma prevalentemente imperfettiva, dato che focalizza un evento che dura e ne sottolinea l’indeterminatezza: non dà informazioni né circa l'inizio, né circa la fine dell’evento stesso, bensì sul suo perdurare e la possibilità implicita che l'azione prosegua fuori dall'intervallo di tempo considerato.

Questo aspetto imperfettivo non è quello adatto a dare l'idea di un'azione che si è svolta in un periodo di tempo determinato: per questa ragione si usano altri tempi verbali invece dell'imperfetto.

Riguardo alla scelta tra passato remoto e passato prossimo, questo libro spiega:

> Il passato remoto si riferisce a fatti remoti, **cronologicamente o psicologicamente lontani dal presente**, sentiti cioè lontani nella mente di chi parla. Il passato remoto proietta questi fatti in un mondo lontano; gli stessi fatti, se raccontati al passato prossimo, diventano più vicini, più vivi, ci coinvolgono maggiormente. La scelta tra i due tempi diventa quindi spesso una questione di stile, di registro, di scelta personale [...].

Quindi, se il narratore vuol dare l'idea di un fatto concluso e lontano nel tempo, potrebbe anche dire:

> Ogni estate lavorai là, fino ai miei 18 anni.

La scelta tra passato prossimo e remoto dipende anche da come prosegue la narrazione. Per esempio, se si continua dicendo "Quindi, conosco bene quel posto", si userebbe il passato prossimo perché si sta spiegando qualcosa che

> ha dei collegamenti con il presente, con un implicito risultato attuale.

Tuttavia, lo stesso libro avverte del fatto che gli usi del passato remoto e del passato prossimo variano regionalmente, soprattutto nel parlato, in modo che nell'Italia del Nord prevale il passato prossimo.

Comment: Ho riportato quello che spiegano i miei libri d'italiano (ho qualche altro libro in cui si trova essenzialmente lo stesso). Possibilmente ci sono situazioni in cui non sia necessario seguire queste regole alla lettera. Spero però di non dover fare un falò con tutti i miei libri d'italiano per la festa di San Giovanni :)

Comment: L'uso del passato prossimo vs. remoto è secondario qui. "Dai 15 ai 18 anni uscivo sempre la sera ("alla" è un altro discorso)" è accettabilissimo pur essendoci una demarcazione temporale chiara. Invece di fare un falò, potresti donarli, no? :-)

Comment: Credo che la scelta di imperfetto oppure passato sia troppo variabile, per contesto semantica e scelta del parlante, per essere riassunta così semplicemente. Confronta "fino ai cinque anni ha succhiato il dito" e "fino ai cinque anni succhiava il dito": dove sta la differenza? Sono intercambiabili o no queste due frasi?

Comment: @user11731289: Se ho capito bene le critiche a questa risposta, a quanto pare, quello che è scritto qui è una "oversimplification" perché ci sono anche situazioni (non spiegate in questa risposta) in cui si usa l'imperfetto per esprimere abitudini nel passato in un periodo di tempo determinato (o qualcosa più o meno simile: non sono ancora riuscita a capire la questione del tutto bene). Ho posto [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12828/) per cercare di chiarire quali sono queste situazioni (cioè, cos'è che manca in questa risposta e nei miei libri d'italiano).

Answer (score 0):

Per due motivi:

(1) L'uso di "ogni" estrae ciascun singolo evento da una catena di eventi uguali e per questo non si focalizza sulla continuità che veicola l'imperfetto. Vale a dire: "nell'anno 1 ho lavorato", "nell'anno 2 ho lavorato" etc.

(2) L'aspetto grammaticale ha molto a che fare con la prospettiva che adotta l'enunciatore. Nel tuo esempio l'enunciatore adotta la prospettiva presente e ripercorre quello che successe in passato. Dicendo "ogni estate lavoravo là", invece, si immedesimerebbe in un suo "io" passato come se stesse rivivendo l'episodio narrato.

Edit. Il limite temporale "fino ai miei 18 anni" rende più acettabile l'uso del passato prossimo, come scrive diversamente @charo sopra. Tuttavia ci sono casi in cui anche l'imperfetto è compatibile con "fino":  "Lei fino a qualche anno fa andava a Cervia in un albergo..." https://books.google.de/books?id=ygULjkV9l4gC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22fino+a+qualche+anno+fa+andava%22&source=bl&ots=ZEl9z4MBNL&sig=ACfU3U0ke_eJvago424UkwjaGD-WWOdlbA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRrfPShp3pAhWiy6YKHXCICZMQ6AEwAnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22fino%20a%20qualche%20anno%20fa%20andava%22&f=false

Comment: Sono confuso col primo punto perchè ho trovato anche dell'espressioni simili in cui si usa l'imperpetto.
Ex:  ogni venerdi’ ci incontravamo al bar ( https://blogs.transparent.com/ italian/passato-prossimo-e-imperfetto/).

Comment: In questo esempio, l'imperfetto esegue la sua tipica funzione di esprimere azioni abituali. Se invece uno dicesse "ogni venerdì ci siamo incontrati al bar" lo farebbe in un contesto in cui sia stato accusato di qualcosa, per dire, e si giustifichi davanti a un giudice a mo' di "non posso essere stato io perché il reato è successo di venerdì e ogni venerdì da aprile a maggio i miei amici e io ci siamo incontrati al bar". L'aspetto grammaticale in italiano è uno dei punti più difficili da capire per parlanti stranieri.

Comment: In questo contesto, è più chiara l'utilizzazione del passato prossimo, grazie.

Answer (score 0):

In realtà con il passato prossimo non si vuole esprimere l'azione nel suo aspetto abituale quanto nel suo aspetto fattuale.

Entrambe le frasi sono corrette

IMPERFETTO - ASPETTO ABITUALE - ad esempio per descrivere come solevo impiegare il tempo
Ogni estate lavoravo là, fino ai miei 18 anni.

PASSATO PROSSIMO - ASPETTO FATTUALE - ad esempio per descrivere un'esperienza di vita.
Ogni estate ho lavorato là, fino ai miei 18 anni.