# Uso dell'imperfetto in frasi come "si succhiava il dito fino ai cinque anni"

Tags: word-usage, verbs, tenses

Si tratta di una domanda correlata a [quest'altra](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/12821/).

In una risposta è apparso questo esempio di frase che esprime un'abitudine nel passato con un'espressione che delimita la durata nel tempo (l'ho modificata leggermente per renderla più idiomatica):

> Si è succhiato il dito fino ai cinque anni.

Mi è sembrato capire dai commenti, però, che la stessa idea (o un'idea simile, ma forse c'è qualche differenza) si possa anche esprimere con questa frase:

> Si succhiava il dito fino ai cinque anni.

Personalmente, questa ultima frase non mi suona bene, cosa che non vuol dire nulla poiché non sono italiana. Potrebbe trattarsi semplicemente di un'impressione causata dalle mie lingue.

La mia sensazione, forse sbagliata, è che l'imperfetto, che di solito rende l'idea di un evento che perdura di forma indeterminata nel tempo, non si accordi bene con la volontà di esprimere un'azione che si è svolta durante un periodo di tempo determinato.

Allora, vi chiedo: posso riferirmi a un'abitudine nel passato delimitata nel tempo con una frase con il verbo all'imperfetto come quella che ho scritto o forse usando l'imperfetto l'interpretazione della frase è diversa? Cambia forse qualche sfumatura nel significato rispetto a usare il passato prossimo (o il passato remoto)? In quali situazioni si usa l'imperfetto in questo tipo di frasi? O forse non c'è nessuna differenza tra una frase e l'altra e si possono usare indistintamente?

In una risposta alla domanda che ho menzionato sopra, appare l'esempio

> Lei fino a qualche anno fa andava a Cervia in un albergo.

La mia impressione è che si tratta di una situazione diversa: secondo me, l'espressione "fino a qualche anno fa" non delimita in modo determinato il tempo in cui termina l'evento, cioè non si sa esattamente quando finisce.

Comment: Sì l´imperfetto è pienamente compatibile e in alcuni casi perfino necessario. Non si direbbe "Cosa vuoi spiegarmi tu che fino a 5 anni hai ancora succhiato le dita?".

Comment: Questo "ancora" e questo "fino" non sono un po' incoerenti tra di loro? "Ancora" dà l'idea di una situazione che dura nel tempo, mentre "fino" indica qualcosa che è finita in quel momento.

Comment: E per quale ragione si dovrebbe dire "si succhiava il dito fino ai 5 anni" invece di "si è succhiato il dito fino ai 5 anni"?

Comment: Invece, "Cosa vuoi spiegarmi tu che a 5 anni ti succhiavi ancora il dito?" mi suona bene perché la fine dell'evento è indeterminata.

Comment: A parte le considerazioni sui tempi verbali, “succhiare il dito/le dita” non è idiomatico: il modo abituale per dirlo è “succhiarsi il dito” (o “il pollice”).

Comment: Grazie, @DaG: ho modificato le frasi.

Comment: Ho rimosso molti commenti che erano solo botta e risposta su questioni non attinenti alla domanda.

Comment: @charo In frasi come queste, l'"ancora" indica un ritardo, cioè un prolungamento di tempo, un'aggiunta. "Fino ai cinque anni ti succhiavi il dito" è più neutro di "Fino ai cinque anni ti succhiavi ancora il dito", che sottintende che l'abitudine avrebbe dovuto cessare prima dei cinque anni. Oppure, altro esempio: "ancora mi dici che ho torto" sottintende che non è più tempo per dirlo, però potrebbe pure riferirsi a un'aggiunta concettuale (non temporale): "mangi più di me, e ancora mi dici che mangio troppo" (colloquiale).

Comment: Io non sono per niente abituata a usare frasi di questo genere. Ci sono parecchi utenti italiani che affermano con molta sicurezza che si usano (e che, per questa ragione, quello che dicono alcuni miei libri e che  ho riportato in una risposta è sbagliato: può darsi che sia così: a volte i libri per stranieri fanno "oversimplification"): non lo metto in dubbio. Non  capisco perché, però, non posso fare una domanda per cercare di capire l'uso che si fa di questo tipo di frasi (cioè, cos'è che  manca nei miei libri). E anche per altre persone che hanno imparato l'italiano con gli stessi libri.

Comment: @DaG: sicuramente è come dici e, infatti, nelle mie lingue è lo stesso: "xuclar-se (o xumar-se) el dit" / "chuparse el dedo". Tuttavia, ricercando con Google, trovo molte occorrenze di "ha succhiato il dito", "succhia il dito" (senza "si"), "succhiare il dito".