# Uso della preposizione in espressioni come "esco alla sera"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/12823/) è apparsa questa frase tratta da un libro (grassetto mio):

> Uscivo sempre **alla** sera.

L'uso della preposizione articolata "alla" ha attirato la mia attenzione: io avrei detto

> Uscivo sempre **la** sera.

Ricercando su Google Libri, ho trovato un altro esempio nel volume 2 delle [*Opere* di Goffredo Parise](https://books.google.es/books?id=dr5LAAAAMAAJ&q=%22esco+alla+sera%22&dq=%22esco+alla+sera%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwih6dSBpp3pAhU54eAKHUYQAlM4ChDoATABegQIBxAB) (grassetto mio):

> Per abitudine esco **alla** sera d'ufficio, passeggio per le strade, senza alcuna preferenza; guardo indifferentemente le case, le vetrine dei negozi, e gli oggetti che sono esposti nelle vetrine.

Qualcuno mi sa spiegare qualcosa sull'uso della preposizione articolata al posto dell'articolo in questa espressione? Cioè, si tratta di un uso popolare? regionale? letterario? arcaizzante? colloquiale?

Ho cercato alla voce "sera" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato esempi della locuzione "alla sera" usata in questo modo.

Si usa anche la preposizione articolata con altri verbi e altre espressioni di tempo? Per esempio, si potrebbe dire "vado a fare la spesa al pomeriggio, alla mattina, alla domenica, ecc."?

Comment: Si usa parecchio in Piemonte e non è sicuramente standard. Visto che Parise era veneto, può darsi che questo fenomeno si verifichi anche in altre regioni dell'Italia settentrionale.

Comment: È italiano normalissimo: tra l'altro la preposizione _a_ “Introduce complementi di tempo più o meno determinato: al mattino, alla sera (anche la mattina, la sera); a notte inoltrata; alle due, alle cinque; a Natale, a Pasqua; a colazione, ai pasti; al sabato (= ogni sabato)” (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/a2/, punto 3).

Comment: @DaG Può darsi, ma "cosa fai alla sera?" mi suona molto inconsueto cosi come anche "dove vai al pomeriggio?"...

Comment: Forse è meno frequente, ma, a quanto ne so, meno frequente non è lo stesso di "non standard". No?

Comment: "vado a fare la spesa al pomeriggio, alla mattina, alla domenica, ecc."? Sì, sono tutte normalissime, come pure "di sera", "di sabato". Ci sono eccezioni-asimmetrie, per esempio non si dice "esco a notte", ma si può dire "esco a notte fonda",  e generalmente non si dice "esco di notte fonda" (questi casi sono diversi perché non usano l'articolo).

Comment: @Nico “Cosa fai alla sera?” a me suona normalissimo. Suppongo dipenda dalla parte d'Italia in cui si cresce.

Comment: @egreg Non dico assolutamente che sia scorretto. A me sa molto di piemontesismo (dico da piemontese). Sono sicuro che se al ginnasio avessi scritto "non so cosa fare al pomeriggio", mi sarei rirovato una bella sottolineatura rossa sotto il sintagma preposizionale magari come un commento del tipo "perché mai dovresti fargli qualcosa?". Penso anche dipenda da fattori come socializzazione, formazione scolastica etc.

Comment: @egreg: Precisamente questo è il senso della mia domanda: qual è l'uso che se ne fa? Forse è in certo modo "regionale" (nel senso che non è usato in certe zone)? Dipende magari da fattori come quelli che ha menzionato Nico? O forse si usa in tutta Italia, ma in certe zone si usa di meno?

Comment: @Charo Per questo sarebbe interessante sentire l'opinioni di utenti che provengono da regioni diverse.

Comment: Come pura opinione personale, da romano che ogni tanto sobbalza sentendo un settentrionalismo (come il “solo più” di un'altra domanda), “alla sera” mi suona normale e, semmai, un po' più ricercato di “di sera” o “la sera”.

Comment: Purtroppo ci vorrebbe un sacco di pazienza per fare una ricerca con Google Books o altri corpora, perché bisognerebbe distinguere l'uso descritto nella domanda dalle invocazioni alla sera, da espressioni del tipo “dalla mattina alla sera” e così via.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG, e ho l'impressione che questo altro tipo di espressioni siano, purtroppo, più frequenti. L'unico che si può fare è cercare di comparare la frequenza di frasi (per esempio, "esce la sera", "esce di sera" ed "esce alla sera").

Comment: @Charo Perché "purtroppo"?

Comment: @DaG Nonostante alcuni contesti in cui le diverse forme possono essere equivalenti, ci sono casi che mi paiono indubbi. Se si tratta di un periodo specifico, direi che esiste solo la possibilità di usare l'articolo senza preposizione: "il pomeriggio/la sera del 2.05.2020", e non "al pomeriggio/alla sera del..." .

Comment: Una semplice ricerca in Google della cooccorrenza di "sera" con "lavorava" rivela una chiara maggioranza di "la sera/di sera" vs. "alla sera". Questa sarebbe la pista da seguire.